# Creating UI comment component with blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create a comments component with Blaze but i don't know how to handle the replies.

This is the schema for the 'comment' element:

_id, authorId, message, replies (those are comment ids), isReply (boolean).

Then I created a template with html

```
{{#each message}}
 <div class="message">
   <h2>{{author}}</h2>
   <p>{{message</p>
   <a class="button">Reply</a>
 </div>
     {{#each replies}}
       <div class="message">
         <h2>{{author}}</h2>
         <p>{{message</p>
         <a class="button">Reply</a>
       </div>
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Well, how do I handle the replies of the replies? Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the templates *recursively*! [An example](https://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/5yt6M/)

In your case, something like the following:

```
{{#each message}}
 <div class="message">
   <h2>{{author}}</h2>
   <p>{{message</p>
   <a class="button">Reply</a>
 </div>
     {{#each replies}}
       {{> reply}}
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}

<template name="reply">
  <div class="message">
  <h2>{{author}}</h2>
  <p>{{message</p>
  <a class="button">Reply</a>
  {{#each replies}}
    {{> reply}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

You'll need a `replies` helper for the `reply` template that gets the replies to that reply.

Comment: Thank you Michel. How I can match both helpers now?  I mean making the replies one showing the proper array of reply messages.

Comment: It depends on how you're modeling the replies to replies. Is there a _parent reply_ key?